# Log the type used with the generic ILogger<T> via Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I am currently using this output template with Serilog:

```
"outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] [{MachineName}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

I would like to add the class that I specify when declaring the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` logger that I inject, i.e. if I declare `ILogger<MyType>` then I would like to output `MyType` via the template.

I know I can add the whole context but I read that this comes with a performance penalty, so currently I add the class by adding `nameof(MyType)` to each message - which is a mess.

Is there an enricher or something similar that will make the type available in the template (or just prefix each log message with the type)?

Edit:

There isn't much code really, this is how I configure Serilog with the dotnet-core WebApi:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService()
    .UseSerilog();
```

And this is an example of how I use the logger via IOC:

```
private readonly ILogger<MyType> _logger;

public MyType(ILogger<MyType> logger)
{
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}

public void HelloLog()
{
   _logger.LogInformation("hello");
}

// expected log output: "[MyType] hello"
```

I understand from Andy's comment that I could write a LoggingProvider and pass it in the UseSerilog overload that takes a collection of providers. That is something I will look into if nothing easier turns up.

Comment: Provide your code. so that we can provide better suggestions

Comment: Pretty sure you are going to have to create your own `ILoggerProvider` and add it to the `ILoggerFactory`.

Comment: @VimalCK there's no need for extra code in this question. The OP asks how to avoid the call to `Enrich.FromLogContext()` and still get the logger's name

Comment: Don't try to optimize for something that may never become a problem, just because someone said there may be a performance impact. *Logging* has a performance impact, and yet we use it because we need it.

Comment: Agreed, but when I remember correctly the context also returns the full method name and not the more concise type name provided by the logger. I only need the type name (I use a number of adapters with similar functionality and want to know where an event occurred). So reflecting out the context plus using some string.split whatever to get to the type looks like a runtime burden too heavy when the name is actually available as a generic type parameter.

Comment: You can set an additional properties using Serilog `IDiagnosticContext`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type name should be added into the `SourceContext` property of any log events emitted by the `ILogger<T>`, exactly as if you'd used the `ForContext<T>()` or `ForContext(type)` methods on a `Serilog.ILogger`. Using `{SourceContext}` somewhere in your message template should allow you to add just the source name, e.g.

```
"[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] [{MachineName}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

Note that this will output the full name of the type, so will include the namespace.

Comment: I do not wish to output the full name of the type but only the type or class name as provided by the ILogger template parameter. In the text logs SourceContext is fine, but not in some other logging facility (Greylog) and the console.

Comment: I fumbled with the ILoggingProvider list but soon got lost, so I guess Robs answer is as good as it gets.